# Groovy findFiles in upper level directory

Tags: groovy

I am using Jenkins to do a build, and I need to get a list of files.  We had a jenkins file pipeline script that worked great.  We then had to re-arrange the file structure and now findFiles is not finding files.  The code looks like this:

```
feature_files = findFiles(glob: '${WORKSPACE}/../feature-*/package.json')
echo "finding files:${WORKSPACE}/../feature-*/package.json"
filecount = feature_files.size()
echo "file count:${filecount}"
```

now when the first line looked like this:

```
feature_files = findFiles(glob: '${WORKSPACE}/feature-*/package.json')
```

It worked fine.  When I take the output from the first echo,  and use that to do a "ls" on the box,  it lists the files correctly, so they are there.

Does the ".."  not work with findFiles() in groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `findFiles` uses a glob-style expression, `..` does indeed not work.

So I guess you have to modify the `WORKSPACE` property...